# Rails 3 helper for match route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

In a rails 3 application following match route is defined in routes.rb

```
match 'accounts/:account_type/:account_id/edit_account' => 'accounts#edit_account'
```

In controller i redirect to this URL

```
redirect_to "/accounts/account/#{account_id.to_s}/edit_account"
```

It works fine but i need a route helper instead of manually building the URL something like this

```
edit_account_accounts_path(account_id: id, account_type: 'some_type')
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
match 'accounts/:account_type/:account_id/edit_account', to: 'accounts#edit_account', as: 'edit_account_accounts'
```

for more help see [The Lowdown on Routes in Rails 3](https://blog.engineyard.com/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3)

Comment: Yes, i tried this. Still not creating the helper for this route

Comment: Thanks for the help. I removed the :via and replaced 'match' with get. Its works now!